# Safari: changing source then calling play directly raises a DOMError aborterror

Tags: javascript, audio, safari, promise, playback

When changing an audio source then calling play immediately I get a DOMError saying the operation was aborted. So my play promise is rejected yet the audio plays fine.

This seems to be a new issue (since december maybe ?), only appends on safari for me. A workaround at the moment is to wait a little bit before calling play() or to wait for an event like loadeddata.

Is anyone aware of the issue ? What's the correct way to tackle it?

Answer (score -3):

Play method is a promise so you can catch error and handle it properly.

```
video.play().catch((error) => {
 console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: "So my play promise is rejected yet the audio plays fine" - I know I can catch it, that's not the issue. The issue is getting a random DOMError in safari when it works in other browsers, plus the audio still plays regardless of the promise being rejected

Comment: related: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted